# Office Add-ins excel extension is not working on IE11 with 'import axios' statement

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, office-js, office-addins

I'm currently developing a Excel extension for my company with Office Add-ins and Reactjs.

Lately I've been using Axios in order to make http requests to get data from a remote back-end service. The issue is that the statement "import axios from 'axios'" is not handled in IE11 and the application runs into an exception when this statement is present in a script file. The exception is :
*Office.js has not fully loaded. Your app must call "Office.onReady()" as part of it's loading sequence (or set the "Office.initialize" function).* In itself that doesn't say a lot except that "the code does not compile".

After a few researches on my own I discovered that IE11 needs polyfill in order to make it work since it doesn't natively support the most recent js scripts (ES6, promises by example).

I've tried many kinds of combinations with babel/polyfill, react-app-polyfill, es-promise with no result so far. Happily, in a another application I've been working on recently (VueJs with axios), I met the same problem and just adding 'import babel/polyfill' did the trick.

I would like to know if anyone has succeeded in doing what I am trying to do for a few days and if not, any help will be appreciated. Some of my coworkers are using Windows 7 or Windows Server 2019 and I really need this excel extension to function with IE11.

Thank you for your help.

**Edit on 06/29 :**

Here is what I have in my **index.js** :

```
import "office-ui-fabric-react/dist/css/fabric.min.css";
import App from "./components/App";
import { AppContainer } from "react-hot-loader";
import { initializeIcons } from "office-ui-fabric-react/lib/Icons";
import * as React from "react";
import * as ReactDOM from "react-dom";
/* global AppCpntainer, Component, document, Office, module, React, require */

initializeIcons();

let isOfficeInitialized = false;

const title = "Contoso Task Pane Add-in";

const render = Component => {
  ReactDOM.render(
    <AppContainer>
      <Component title={title} isOfficeInitialized={isOfficeInitialized} />
    </AppContainer>,
    document.getElementById("container")
  );
};

Office.initialize = () => {
  isOfficeInitialized = true;
  render(App);
};

render(App);

if (module.hot) {
  module.hot.accept("./components/App", () => {
    const NextApp = require("./components/App").default;
    render(NextApp);
  });
}
```

**commands.js :** You can see that I have a commented import statement in this file regarding axios. My intent is to make it work in the dataservice instead but I put that statement here just for testing purpose. The dataservice class itself has only one dependency : axios.

```
import "babel-polyfill";
// import axios from 'axios';
import DataService from '../server/dataservice';
```

Comment: Very likely that you have another issue with your add-in, I've successfully used Axios on multiple add-ins which shipped. Can you share you initialization code?

Comment: Hello Mavi, thank you for your answer. I've found a workaround by using fetch instead of axios. But on of my coworker is using axios in a code that we integrate to my application in the future. If you can give me your insights about what is going wrong with Axios it can be some help in the future. I edited my first post to give more information.